# Reduce the number of variables used in my if-else statements

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, variables, reduce

I know it sounds terrible but in my java program I have about 100 if-else statements, all containing 3 variables that have to stay unique to those if-else blocks, 1 is a flag used to know when its the first time ever hitting that if-else block, and the other 2 are both strings and are temp variables holding that data that was used last time it ran through that if-else block, so it can be compared to the data running through this time around, sorry if it sounds sloppy, I hate the idea of having so many if-else blocks, but right now Im more concerned about the variables, because if I make 3 variables for each block that is an extra 300 variables. Any suggestions on something I could implement to reduce the amount of variables, one idea I have was 1 array for all the flags and then a 2d array holding the 2 strings for each if-else block. Thanks Beef.

**Edited:** to show sample of the first 2 if-else blocks, all the other have the same code inside just with different names for the flag and temp variables ex. `ac101Flag, tempAC101Start, tempAC101End`

```
                // AC 101
                if (room.equals("FEB 2009") || room.equals("FEB 2011") ||room.equals("FEB 2013") || room.equals("FEB 2015") || room.equals("FEB 2017") ||
                        room.equals("FEB 2021") || room.equals("FEB 2023") || room.equals("FEB 2025") || room.equals("FEB 2027") || room.equals("FEB 2029")) {
                    instanceNum = 4;
                    devID = 130200;
                    if (ac101Flag == false) {
                        Delete();
                        Insert();
                        ac101Flag = true;
                        tempAC101Start = Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                        tempAC101End = Double.parseDouble(finalEnd.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                    }
                    //Insert();
                    else if (tempAC101Start <= (Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'))) && tempAC101End >= Double.parseDouble(finalEnd.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'))) {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Insert();
                        tempAC101Start = Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                        tempAC101End = Double.parseDouble(finalEnd.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                    }   
                }
                // AC 102
                else if(room.equals("FEB 1130")) {
                    instanceNum = 4;
                    devID = 130400;
                    if (ac102Flag == false) {
                        Delete();
                        Insert();
                        ac102Flag = true;
                        tempAC101Start = Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                        tempAC101End = Double.parseDouble(finalEnd.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                    }
                    //Insert();
                    else if (tempAC101Start <= (Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'))) && tempAC101End >= Double.parseDouble(finalEnd.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'))) {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Insert();
                        tempAC101Start = Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                        tempAC101End = Double.parseDouble(finalEnd.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.'));
                    }   
                }
```

Comment: Show the first handful of if/else blocks of that code.

Comment: @nos refer to edit for an example of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Just to give a more concrete demonstration of the answer, I think you want something like:

```
class Foo // Rename this!
{
    private double start;
    private double end;
    private boolean flag;

    public void handleValue(double newStart, double newEnd)
    {
        // Insert code here
    }
}

private static void insertFoo(Map<String, Foo> map, String... rooms)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    for (String room : rooms)
    {
        map.put(room, foo);
    }
}

...
HashMap<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
insertFoo(map, "FEB 2009", "FEB 2011", ...);
insertFoo(map, "FEB 1130");
```

Then in your loop, just use:

```
Foo foo = map.get(room);
foo.update(start, end); // Parsed from the current finalStart/finalEnd
```

---

It's hard to say for sure without seeing your code, but it *sounds* like you should encapsulate all of this in a data structure:

- The three variables (state and falg)
- "Something" to represent the condition of the `if` part. The exact nature of this will depend on what you've got

You can then run through a list of these `ConditionBlock` objects (or whatever you choose to call them) and check whether the block "matches" in the current context, updating it where appropriate.

If you can give us a small example of the original code, we can probably refactor it for you fairly easily.

EDIT: As I apparently haven't been clear about introducing the local variables for the sake of parsing in *one* place, I'd do something like this (as *one* first step):

```
// TODO: Don't use double here - it's completely inappropriate. Use
// BigDecimal if you absolutely must, but preferrably use a time-related
// type, e.g. something from Joda Time (http://joda-time.sf.net)
double parsedStart = Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5)
                                                  .replace(':', '.'));

// TODO: Put all of these constants in a HashSet<String> and use contains
if (room.equals("FEB 2009") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2011") ||
    room.equals("FEB 2013") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2015") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2017") ||
    room.equals("FEB 2021") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2023") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2025") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2027") || 
    room.equals("FEB 2029")) {

    instanceNum = 4;
    devID = 130200;
    // TODO: Change to if (!ac101Flag)
    if (ac101Flag == false) {
        // TODO: Rename these methods to follow Java naming conventions
        Delete();
        Insert();
        ac101Flag = true;
        tempAC101Start = parsedStart;
        tempAC101End = parsedEnd;
    }
    //Insert();
    else if (tempAC101Start <= parsedStart && tempAC101End >= parsedEnd) {

    }
    else
    {
        Insert();
        tempAC101Start = parsedStart;
        tempAC101End = parsedEnd;
    }   
}
```

Comment: @Beef: Is there any pattern to the logic of the if/else blocks? Is there any reason why you've got calls to `parseDouble` *everywhere* instead of just in one place?

Comment: The reason I use that `parseDouble` everywhere is that everytime it enters an if-else blocks the value of `finalStart` and `finalEnd` will be different, and it can come back to the blocks, so if it enters AC101 it saves those temps, it could jump to 50 other blocks before it comes back to AC101 but I still need to have the AC101 data for when it does come back, if that makes sense

Comment: @Beef: You're calling `Double.parseDouble(finalStart.substring(0, 5).replace(':', '.')` in *every case* - so you could do that in one place before the start of the `if` block. You can *use* those values differently in each case, but it would at least remove that bit of repetition.

Comment: I use the original string of `finalStart` in the `Insert()` method, so I cant call the parse till after I call the `Insert()`

Comment: @Beef: Oh, you mean the `Insert` method (which should be named `insert` for Java conventions, btw) changes the value of `finalStart`? Eek. To be honest, I'm not sure that refactoring from where you've got to is the best way of getting to clean code... I suspect I'd start from scratch with an analysis of the bigger problem.

Comment: no, the `Insert` function doesnt change the value of `finalStart` but `finalStart` is holding a `time` in a `string` such as `08:00:00` and the `Insert` method takes that `string` and inserts it into a row of data into a column that is a time datatype in a `database` using `jdbc-odbc` so `finalStart` needs to keep that format until it is inserted or I will get an error from the `database` because the format wont be acceptable for the time datatype of the column

Comment: @Beef: I never suggested changing the value of `finalStart`, so how would my suggestion of extracting all that parsing cause problems? You're aware that calling `substring` doesn't change the string that you call it on, right?

Comment: the reason I cant move it is because I need the temps to only change right before they leave the if/else, if I change it at the start of the if/else then the temps with always equal the `finalStart` and `finalEnd` which defeats the purpose of my nested if/else comparing the temp to the parsed version of `finalStart` and `finalEnd` which if I didnt have that else/if I wouldnt need any of the temps at all

Comment: the big picture of this if/else is that `finalEnd` and `finalStart` hold a start time and an end time, so when I run through a if/else I save that start time and end time to the temps, and then the next time it hits that same block `finalStart` and `finalEnd` are different times, I then check to see if they fall in between the temps start times and end times so if they do I can ignore cause that time slot is already occupied

Comment: @Beef: I wasn't suggesting changing the values of *any* existing variables. I was suggesting introducing two new local variables which would hold the result of parsing `finalStart` and `finalEnd` before you start with the if/else blocks. You can then use those local variables within the code. Will edit my answer to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: @Beef: The next time you run through the code, you parse them again... but just the once. See my edit. And note the suggestion that you *don't* use double for this...

Comment: ooh so `parsedStart` and `parsedEnd` will be changing everytime but before they change I'll loading them into the temps

Comment: @Beef: Yes. Just before you start the if/else block nightmare, you extract the expressions you'll *always* be evaluating. See how even in the bit of code I changed, it makes life a lot simpler?

Comment: yes, Thanks, I'll look into those other changes you suggest too, still leaves me with the main thing I want to avoid, which is creating 3 variables for each if/else block and I have a 115 of them...

Comment: @Beef: For that, see the start of my answer. It sounds like each type should have the fields used only in that block currently, and a set of strings to match on.

Comment: as in a class to hold the boolean, and 2 string temps, and then array of that class? such as the below answer

Comment: @Beef: An array to hold the boolean, two string temps, *and the set of strings that object is applicable to* (so "FEB 2009" etc in your first case). I'd use a list rather than an array, personally...

Comment: So from my understanding I would be making a class, with a boolean, an array with the 2 temps, and another array of all the strings to match on, and then make a list that will be holding 115 of these classes? sorry, I am a little confused with this part

Comment: @Beef: Not an array of strings - a `HashSet<String>`. And yes, you'd then create a list of lots of those. Alternatively, you may be able to create a `HashMap<String, YourClass>` where you'd use the same reference for several different values (and you wouldn't have the set within the object). That would be better than iterating over the whole list...

Comment: Alright, thanks, I never really used either lists or maps in java so maybe I'll check out `HashMap`s and give them a try, thanks again for all the help

Comment: @Beef: I've edited my answer to give a bit more context. To be honest, it sounds like you've been given a problem which is rather more complicated than your experience is appropriate for. If this is professional work, I suggest you ask to pair program with someone more senior who can lead you through this in person.

Comment: thanks, Im actually college student on a work term, I have been able to do lots of this but sometimes I just know there would be better ways to approach some problems, and unfortunately Im not in a strictly programming department so there isnt many people I can seek for help

Answer (score 2):

The one issue that was not clear in your question was how similar the if blocks are, In any case you might have an if block ancestor class with a common inteface and adopting the ideas above, create an instance for each if block, with the state variables as part of the object, then create a collection of those objects and then just loop through the collection of if blocks calling each in turn.  Each if-block instance would inherit the common variable and be unique to the object (encapsulation) and each block could have tailored code for each special case for each if block.

The code overhead for defining each instance would be greater and the execution time would be more but you would not have to create seperate variables and you would mix and match and change order of the if blocks dynamically if you wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a class that has the three fields. Create an array of this class for the number of instances that you need to maintain.

```
private class Vars{
   int val1;
   String val2, val3;
}

private Vars[] allVars = new Vars[300];

void myMethod(){
   if (condition1){
       allVals[0].val1 = ...;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using polymorphism.

Each block has behavior and data. So make each block an object that implements an interface.

Each block object can hold onto a state object like @Jon Skeet suggests.

First, pick an object. That might be with your existing if statements, or if possible, via some simpler mapping.

Then, just call the method on the object you've picked.

```
class BlockState {
  boolean hasBeenCalled = false;
  String last1;
  String last2;
}

class Block1 implements Runnable {
   BlockState m_blockState = new BlockState();
   public void run() { ... }
}

... 
class BlockN implements Runnable {
   BlockState m_blockState = new BlockState();
   public void run() { ... }
}

...

class LongChainOfIfs
  void foo() {
     Runnable runnable = null;
     if ( ... ) runnable = ...
     else if ( ... ) runnable = ...
     ...
     else runnable = ...

     runnable.run();
   }
 }
```